# how to increment decrement counter in listview for a single item

Tags: json, flutter, listview

I am a beginner and I am trying to increment and decrement the counter for a single item list. Its displaying the counter perfectly but when I tap on "+" it increments the counter for all the list items or when I press "-" the counter gets decremented in all the list items. I am not getting any errors either. I am trying to achieve this so that I can pass the incremented or decremented counter with its list data  to the other cart screen. I am using json data which I am getting from the node js backend which i have created

```
[image][1]
[image][3]
[image][2]

     


  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/NetworkHandler.dart';
    
    class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState();
    }
    
    class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen> {
    
      NetworkHandler networkHandler = NetworkHandler();
      List listOfProducts;
      bool addproduct ;
      int counter=1;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        addproduct = false;
        fetchData();
       
      }
    
      void fetchData() async {
        var response = await networkHandler.get("/add_product/getproducts");
        setState(() {
          listOfProducts = response["data"];
    
        });
      }
    
      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          counter++;
        });
      }
    
      void _decrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          counter--;
        });
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: "Products",),
                  Tab(text: "Cart",)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body:
            TabBarView(
              children: [
                listOfProducts == null ? Center(
                  child: Text("We don't have any Products Yet"),
                ) : ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return
                    Container(
                      height: 150,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 15, 8),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Column(
                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            
                            children: <Widget>[
    
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 110,
                                width: 100,
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                         image: NetworkHandler().getImage(listOfProducts[index] ['_id']),
                                          fit: BoxFit.contain),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                               Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    
                                  children: [
                                    //productname (),
                                    Text(
                                      listOfProducts[index]['product_name'].toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
    
                                   
                                    Container(
                                      height: 30,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-120,
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [                         
                                          Container(child: addproduct?addmore():add()
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
    
                },
                itemCount: listOfProducts == null ? 0 : listOfProducts.length,
                ),
                /* Cart Screen */Container()
              ],
            ),
            ),
        );
      }
    
    
      Widget add(){
        return Container(
          height: 20,
          child: OutlineButton(
              onPressed: (){
    
                setState(() {
                  addproduct=true;
                });
              },
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
              //color: Colors.blueAccent,
              //disabledBorderColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Text("ADD +",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16,fontWeight: 
                          FontWeight.normal),
              )
          ),
        );
    
      }
    
    
      Widget addmore(){
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
              topRight: Radius.circular(4),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){
    
                  if(counter==1) {
                    setState(() {
                      addproduct=false;
                    });
                  }
                  else{
                    _decrementCounter();
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 18,
                  width: 25,
    
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                      ),
                      //border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
    
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle, color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  child: Center(
    
                    child: Text("-", style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 18,
                width: 25,
    
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("$counter", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16,),),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  if(counter<=99){
                    _incrementCounter();
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 18,
                  width: 25,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                      ),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle, color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("+" , style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
    
      }
    
    
    
    }



   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo8Y8.jpg
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C69KA.jpg
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymut0.jpg
```

Comment: I hope this can help with your problem [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58291680/9483327](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58291680/9483327)

Comment: i tried that but i don't know how it didn't work for me

Comment: when i tapped on  "+" it did not increment after 1

Comment: and then it also doesn't  solve the problem for my bool variable

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal as there is only one counter variable in charge of tracking a list of items.

A solution is to implement a simple Product class as shown below.

```
class Product {
  String id;
  String productName;
  int counter = 0;
  bool addProduct = false;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.productName,
  });
}
```

Then, in your fetch data method your create Product instances from data you received.

```
 void fetchData() async {
    // async call

    listOfProducts = [
      {'_id': '1', 'product_name': 'a'},
      {'_id': '2', 'product_name': 'b'}
    ].map((item) {
      return Product(
        id: item['_id'],
        productName: item['product_name'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

In your ListView, you will pass down the index to methods such as add or addmore.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    ...,
    Container(
      child: listOfProducts[index].addProduct
          ? addmore(index)
          : add(index),
    );
  },
  itemCount: listOfProducts == null ? 0 : listOfProducts.length,
)
```

Finally, you need to update all setState statement where you reference an item in listOfProducts.

```
void _incrementCounter(int index) {
  setState(() {
    listOfProducts[index].counter++;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: pondData.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      var values = pondData[index];
      int n = index+1;

      return ListTile(
        title: Text("${values.name}"),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        leading: Text(n.toString()),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, left: 10, right: 10),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: you can do it that way,,, basically index contains the number, so you do around with the index,,,  in mycase i referenced the index to a variable n, increaemented it and then called it in the text widget.... so if you can play around with the index, then there you will your way out